# Socicons not working showing

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm using something called "socicon" http://www.socicon.com but it's not working as I want.

it work in the html documents 1,2 and 3 but if I try to use it in any of the html documents in the stuff folder it doesn't work.

this is what it looks like

folder "project name"

- folder "stuff"
- folder "css"

  - font.css
  - MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot
  - MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.otf
  - MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg
  - MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf
  - MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff
- 1.html
- 2.html
- 3.html

html

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fonts.css" />
</head

<body
  <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="../../index.html">Bengzoor</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com"><span class="symbol">facebook</span></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitter.com"><span class="symbol">twitter</span></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Terroristutrotaren"><span class="symbol">youtube</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>
<body
```

css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
    src: url('.MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot');
    src: url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.woff') format('woff'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.svg#MonoSocialIconsFont') format('svg');
    src: url('MonoSocialIconsFont-1.10.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.symbol, a.symbol:before {
    font-family: 'Mono Social Icons Font';
    -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -ms-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -o-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a.symbol:before {
    content: attr(title);
    margin-right: 0.3em;
    font-size: 130%;
}
```

Comment: Check the path to the css file, it looks like you're using relative paths. Be sure that the html files in the "stuff" folder are pointed at the correct path.

Comment: -Well i got it working, but I got another problem and that is if I update the site and then I don't mean like clicking on the update icon or F5. I mean if  Click on the url ant hit enter then I will only see the text instead of the symbol isn't that odd?

Comment: This normally occurs when the font is not loaded properly. Most often it is due to cross-domain issues, but since you seem to be loading the font locally I'm not sure.

Check your console (or firebug, or any other web developer tools) to see if there are any errors. The other thing to try would be removing the extra periods from the font name. Just in case it's messing something up.